# How to copy complete tables between PostgreSQL Databases with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to **copy some tables** from a **production system** to a **test system** on a regular basis. Both systems run a PostgreSQL server. I want to copy only specific tables from production to test.

I´ve already set up a **foreach which iterates over the table names** I want to copy. The problem is, that the table structures may change during development process and the copy job might fail.

So is there a way to use some kind auf "automatic mapping"? Cause the tables in both systems always have exactly the same structure. Or is there some kind of "Copy table" procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove mapping and structure in your pipeline . Then it will using the default mapping behavior. Given your tables always have the same schema, both mapping by name and mapping by order should work.

Comment: So this means if I don´t define a mapping DF tries to copy all the source columns to the same columns in the sink automatically?

Comment: as I can tell, some connectors will automatically map by name. But I can’t guarantee all the connectors as ADF supports many connectors. Either by name or order. But in your case, seems it will always work, right?

Comment: And as far as I know, ADF doesn't support postgreSql as sink. Are you using ODBC connector as Sink?